# how can i redirect a user to custom url after adding page through add.php (Facebook)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-page

How can I redirect a user to just added page after adding it through add.php?

let's say my url looks like: http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=API_KEY&pages=1

After selecting a page from the select box and clicking 'Add MY_APP_NAME' user is redirected to the wall of the page instead of to freshly added MY_APP.

**Notice**

I know this type of questions lots of here but i have no found any solution that why i put this question here again.... helps are definitely appreciated

**Tried**

I tried myself like this using Javascript but seriously not success

```
<script>
if (window == top) {
  top.location.href = 'https://apps.facebook.com/abc/' + document.location.href.replace(/https?:\/\/[^/]*\/?/, '');
}
function addToPage(page_id){
   top.location.href = 'http://facebook.com/add.php?api_key=<?php echo C_APP_ID; ?>&pages&perms=publish_stream&page='+page_id;
}
</script>
```

**See Image**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?  
  app_id=APP_ID&
  display=popup&
  next=https://facebook.com
```

Using this alternative method you can specify the URL to be redirected to after interacting with the dialog to add an application to your page in the `next` parameter.

You could try adding that parameter to your request.

Other possible alternatives for the `next` parameter are -

- `redirect_url`
- `redirect_uri`

Both are used elsewhere when dealing with redirecting users - perhaps one of them will assist you as well...

Comment: I see you are using a different URL to add applications to pages.  Have you tried to use the URL example that I gave? `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab`